# Removing leading and trailing semicolons from a text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose in a cell sometime text looks like

```
;ABCD;EFGH

;;ABCD;EFGH;
```

How to remove semicolon only from beginning and end. The outcome should be

```
ABCD;EFGH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but it works!

```
Public Function SplitSemiColon(s As String) As String
    While Left(s, 1) = ";"
        s = Mid(s, 2)
    Wend

    While Right(s, 1) = ";"
        s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Wend

    SplitSemiColon = s
End Function
```

Place the code in a new module and use the function on the worksheet like this (for example):

```
=SplitSemiColon(A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no spaces, another alternative can be to convert them to spaces, trim, and convert back:

```
=Substitute(Trim(Substitute(A1,";"," "))," ",";")
```

`TRIM` removes extra spaces, so the above would turn `;A;;;B;` into `A;B`, but VBA `Trim` doesn't:

```
[A1] = Replace(Trim(Replace([A1],";"," "))," ",";")        ' ";A;;;B;" into "A;;;B"
```

---

If there are any spaces, they can be replaced with a different character, but it gets too messy:

```
=Substitute(Substitute(Trim(Substitute(Substitute(A1," ","_"),";"," "))," ",";"),"_"," ")
```