# VBA - How to remove value from string delimited with character

Tags: arrays, vba, string, delimiter

I'm trying to write a function that gets both the name of the column header and the value I want to remove from the string.
The function will remove the value from the string in the cell that delimited by ";" and write the string back to the cell.

**for example if I summon the function with "B":**

(The range of the column name I got from the function `getHeadersRange` and it works fine).

[image]

so far I got:

```
Function ValueUpdateForMultipleValues(colName As String, ValueToDelete As String)

    Dim newItems As Variant
    Set Rng = getHeadersRange(colName)
    
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (colName + " header was Not found")
    Else
    
        For Each cell In Rng
    
            items = Split(cell.Value, ";")
            maxValues = UBound(items)
            
            For i = 0 To maxValues
           
                If items(i) <> ValueToDelete Then
                    newItems = newItems & ";" & items(i)
                End If
                            
            Next i
            cell.Value = newItems
    
        Next cell
    
    End If

End Function
```

I'm not getting any error but the string isn't what I needed and also sometimes the first character is ";" and I cant have it.

Thanks!

Comment: So, do you need ";" character to remain, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use your updated function as:

```
Function ValueUpdateForMultipleValues(colName As String, ValueToDelete As String)
    Dim items As Variant, rng As Range
    Set rng = getHeadersRange(colName)
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (colName & " header was Not found")
    Else
    
        For Each Cell In rng
            items = Split(Cell.value, ";")
            items = Filter(items, ValueToDelete, False)
            Cell.value = Join(items, ";")
        Next Cell
    End If
End Function
'I imagined a function able to return the range based on the column letter:
Function getHeadersRange(strCol As String) As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastR = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, strCol).End(xlUp).row
    Set getHeadersRange = sh.Range(sh.cells(1, strCol), sh.cells(lastR, strCol))
End Function
```

It will remove `ValueToDelete` and its ";" separator. Do you need the separator to remain?

The function can be called as:

```
Sub testValueUpdateForMultipleValues()
  ValueUpdateForMultipleValues "F", "B"
End Sub
```

To process the range in column "F:F", to eliminate "B"...

If the range to be processed is really huge (over a million cells), the function can be adapted, in order to be very fast, working only in memory. I mean, placing the range in an array, process the array and drop its content back at once...

In fact, I will post the updated Function/Sub, too:

```
Function ValueUpdateForMultipleValuesArr(colName As String, ValueToDelete As String)
    Dim items As Variant, rng As Range, Cel As Range, i As Long, arr
    Set rng = getHeadersRange(colName)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (colName & " header was Not found")
    Else
    arr = rng.Value2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            items = Split(arr(i, 1), ";")
            items = Filter(items, ValueToDelete, False)
            arr(i, 1) = Join(items, ";")
        Next i
    End If
    rng.Value2 = arr
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Function
```

It should be called, of course as:

```
ValueUpdateForMultipleValuesArr "F", "B"
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know the `Filter`-function exists. Small remark: I think `ValueUpdateForMultipleValues` should be a Sub, not a Function; and `Cell` should be declared.

Comment: @FunThomas: Thanks! It **can be a Sub**, not returning anything... In fact, it should be recommended to be a `Sub`, I agree. I only tried to adapt the code he had. It works like a function, too. I also posted a version a little faster, the speed difference being considerable in case of huge ranges to be processed. And, yes, `Filter` is an interesting function working on arrays... You can use it to also count the occurrences of a string in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the first character of your string is `;`:

```
' Left function starts from the beginning of your string
' and returns the string up to the specified index
Left(valStr, 1) = ";"
```

If so, you can just cut out the first character from your string:

```
If Left(valStr, 1) = ";" Then

  ' Remove first character of string
  Right(valStr, Len(valStr)-1)

End If
```

To remove excess characters take a look at this answer: [Removing leading and trailing semicolons from a text in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916277/removing-leading-and-trailing-semicolons-from-a-text-in-a-cell)

The following function is used there:

```
Public Function SplitSemiColon(s As String) As String
    While Left(s, 1) = ";"
        s = Mid(s, 2)
    Wend

    While Right(s, 1) = ";"
        s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Wend

    SplitSemiColon = s
End Function
```

Comment: That's good and I will use it, thanks. but still the returned string isn't what I need like in the example (before-after). and also it comes back with many ";" from the left side.

Answer (score 1):

You may explore the use of `Regex` for your need, modify your code to update for the column you need

```
Sub regex()

Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim stringPatter As String
Dim inputRange As Range

stringPatter = ";B"

With regex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = stringPatter
End With

For Each inputRange In Sheet1.Range("A1:A5").Cells

    If regex.Test(inputRange.Value) Then
        inputRange.Value = regex.Replace(inputRange.Value, "")
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comparison of before and after

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using Replace:

```
Function ValueUpdateForMultipleValues(colName As String, ValueToDelete As String)
    retval = " " & Replace(colName, UCase(ValueToDelete), "") & " "    'delete ValueToDelete and add spaces (see below)
    retval = Replace(retval, ";;", ";")             ' correct double ;
    retval = Replace(retval, " ;", "")              ' correct lead ;
    retval = Replace(retval, "; ", "")              ' correct final ;
    ValueUpdateForMultipleValues = Trim(retval)     ' delete extra spaces and return the value
End Function

Sub test()
    a = Array("A;B;C", "A;B;C", "A;B;C;D", "A;B")
    For Each s In a
        Debug.Print ValueUpdateForMultipleValues(CStr(s), "B")
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
A;C
A;C
A;C;D
A
```